# Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/pgoe27.so' : file not found

Tags: odbc, openedge, progress-db

we are trying to connect Progress DB through PHP but we are getting the error below:

> Error: Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/pgoe27.so' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect in /var/www/test/odbcprogrssdb.php on line 7.

Please let me know the correct .so file to use.

We are using OE 11.3 Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct .so file would be pgoe27.so

Does it exist **anywhere** on the system?  Obviously it is being looked for in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc but is not there or, if it is there, lacks permissions.

Is OpenEdge installed on this system?  If it is then you are likely to find the missing .so in $DLC/odbc/lib

You might also want to take a look at $DLC/odbc/example.

Comment: Actually they copied the file pgoe27.so from $DLC/odbc/lib and placed it in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc .But they didnt check whether it lacks permisiions. We have to check it on monday.

Comment: tom, we are getting a different error                            PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]1201, SQL state 60 in SQLConnect in /var/www/test/mysql.php on.  please suggest.